# How to create permanent load with The Grinder

Tags: performance, python, grinder

I want to set `grinder.properties` so, that my `grinder.processes` will start one right after another to provide permanent uninterrupted load (some kind of reliability testing). I checked that one process (25 test cases*50 `grinder.threads` each) takes about 10 minutes, so I could set `grinder.processIncrementInterval = 600000`, but this is not exactly what I want as this time is not constant and there could be breaks between processes or they could overlap each other...